# RSA key-pair generation in golang with 15360 key length is too slow. What need to be done to resolve this?

Tags: java, go, cryptography, rsa, private-key

I tried creating RSA key-pair with 15360 key length in go.

In windows it generates key-pair in ~2 minutes. But from VM it's listening more than ~10 minutes and unable to generate key-pair and ended with socket hang up.

```
privateKey, err := generatePrivateKey(15360)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
}
```

Same in java implementation, its generating key-pair with ~10 minutes in VM 3 out of 5 chances.

In what way I can improve this in go , to avoid such socket hang up failures ?

Comment: Wild guess: [your VM has not enough entropy](https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/random-numbers-generation-in-virtual-machines/) ("randomness") and spends most of its time waiting for more. This is especially likely if the VM hasn't been running very long. It takes time to produce entropy from things like I/O devices.

Comment: Maybe I should have let with this, but the first thing you should consider is why you even need such a ridiculously large key. You're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Why a key length of 15360?

Comment: Why not ? I understood , key length is very large, noticed that too. most maximum  length of key in go 4096 is used  , Then I noticed someone used with key-length of 15360 in java. Its working only time consuming is high. So nothing wrong with key length right. So tried this in go. Facing this issue. How to proceed further.?

Comment: another comment to say that a key length of 15360 is pushing RSA way too far, e.g. [NIST only requires 2048 bit keys](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-131Ar2.pdf).  you're almost certainly better off using a different crypto scheme that provides an equivalent (i.e. 256bit) security level with simpler computational requirements.

Comment: Generating RSA keys requires searching for primes. The larger the primes, the longer it takes to do the search. Fortunately there is no point to RSA keys that large. It takes around O(n) steps to find a prime of n bits. Each step takes around O(n^2 log n) operations so you are looking at roughly O(n^3 log n) operations to find an n-bit prime. The variance in the distribution is such that you'll need to do more than a handful of experiments to estimate the mean, plus VMs are not typically as fast as the native OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested the generation of keys in Go 1.14.6 (Windows 10, no VM, 4 cores), in [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) or (much faster) [ECC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography), using [nilsmagnus's gist](https://gist.github.com/nilsmagnus/bcccb9ec2f30d403ca003bf06a20a4c7)

I do see 10+ minutes needed for a 15360-bit RSA key (equivalent in strength to 256-bit symmetric keys)

```
2020/08/13 07:55:30 2048/224 (rsa-bitsize/ec-bitsize):    1245302200ns    1481396600ns
2020/08/13 07:55:34 3072/256 (rsa-bitsize/ec-bitsize):    2797005900ns      70036800ns
2020/08/13 07:56:41 7680/384 (rsa-bitsize/ec-bitsize):   33954637400ns   11623485000ns
2020/08/13 08:07:56 15360/521 (rsa-bitsize/ec-bitsize): 236410356300ns   17162054200ns
```

[image: generation time 1.14]

With Go 1.15 (released yesterday):

```
2020/08/13 08:11:40 2048/224 (rsa-bitsize/ec-bitsize):    1064054900ns   1486366000ns
2020/08/13 08:11:43 3072/256 (rsa-bitsize/ec-bitsize):    2799028300ns     70949100ns
2020/08/13 08:12:34 7680/384 (rsa-bitsize/ec-bitsize):   35293246300ns   9160064600ns
2020/08/13 08:24:10 15360/521 (rsa-bitsize/ec-bitsize): 236385736600ns  25844676400ns
```

No obvious improvement.

[image: GO 1.15 times]

So using ECC keys instead of RSA would be much faster for that kind of key length.

Comment: Yup, we need to use ECC for faster and in my case, I increased read,write time out value, to ~15 mins, able to create keys by avoiding socket hang up issue.